# Why this error occurs?

Tags: profile, error, access, user-profile

I got this error when write in field: "Description"

[image: error about de insufficient access]

But this profile have permission to Edit
[image: image about the user list of permission]

How can I see this "access right"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to the record itself, or a related record (via Process Builder or Apex Triggers). You'll have to check the sharing for the record. Unfortunately, you can't check this in Lightning (for now), so you'll need to switch to Classic, then click on the Sharing button. You may not have access to this page directly, so you might need to log in as an administrator.

Comment: Right, where can I see this "sharing button"? In the object manager? In the record? This error occur for every record, this ask can be stupid, but I'm newbie in Salesforce, so if you can explain I appreciate it.

Comment: @ErickMori it should be on the record detail page in Classic. You might need to add it to the page layout. I'm mobile right now, but when I get home I'll post a link.